# Visual Studio fatal error C1084: Cannot read include file: 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\map': Permission denied

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++, opencv

Having some problems with Visual C++ express 2010 and getting the same thing with Visual Studio 2010.

I get this error on compilation:

fatal error C1084: Cannot read include file: 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\map': Permission denied

What's odd is this was compiling yesterday, I closed it and went to bed, came back to it this morning and it doesn't compile. I haven't changed anything, what happened ?

Advice would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

It seems this problem only occurs when I include any openCV header file. It was all working before, why not now?

EDIT2:

the problem occurs on a hello world example if I #include map

EDIT3:

went into university and tried it, it works on these machines, seems the problem is specific to my PC. All I can think of is that the file got corrupted somehow.

Comment: Do you need to run Visual Studio as Administrator and forgot to do that this time?

Comment: ty for reply, nope, I am running it as admin.

Comment: did you try this with another demo project? see if you can  get the same error?

Comment: Since you are getting "permission denied" it might be useful to know what the permissions on the map file are.  Looking at my own system (which should be typical) System and Administrators both have 'Full control' and Users have 'Read & Execute' and 'Read' permissions.

Comment: The permission on my map file are the same. I tired making a demo project, it seems the problem only occurs when I try to include opencv library header files.

Comment: So you #include <map> and everything is okay, then you #include some opencv file and everything is not okay?  Weird.  Does it matter which order you include the two files?  The documentation for [C1084](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f1s5tde.aspx) mentions making sure there is "adequate" space in the TMP and TEMP directories.  Are the opencv header files particularly big?

Comment: oh hang on, #include <map> gives the same error. Gonna try it on another machine, maybe something has gone wrong on mine.

Comment: Why would you need to run Visual Studio as admin to open include files? Doesn't make much sense to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the "map" file from another machine into my c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ and now it all works. It must have been corrupted somehow.

Comment: If that worked, I strongly recommend rebuilding your machine (reinstall OS, etc.).  Once you have one issue like this, you are very likely to have similar issues keep cropping up.